# Gatsby build outputs css makes it messy

Tags: gatsby

I'm currently doing a project with Gatsby JS. When I run gatsby build && gatsby serve, when i see the page's source, all of the css is displayed there. 
[image]
Is there a way to hide those messy css on view page source?

currently I import my css on `gatsby-browser.js`

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Your css is messy because you are importing it in gatsby-browser, if you imported your css in a  component, the page source would look cleaner.